# Pass counter value from child component to parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rendering, react-props

There is a child component. There are buttons with weights on it. The load can be selected, or the choice can be removed. The weight of each load is added to the previous one.

Chlld-component:

```
<ul className="lots__list">
 ...
          {filter == "cargo" &&
            lotsSplice.map((item) => (
              <CargoButton
                key={item.id}
                id={item.id}
                weight_value={item.value}
                handleClick={buttonHandler}
                array={lotsSplice}
                card={item}
                ArraySaved={arraySaved}
                isAdded={item.isAdded}
              />
            ))}
        </ul>
```

function buttonHandler(item, isAdded) {
setLotsSplice(
lotsSplice.map((elem) =>
elem.id === item.id ? { ...elem, isAdded: !elem.isAdded } : elem
)
);

```
const tempCargoValue = sumCargoValue;
setSumCargoValue(item.value * 1);

if (isAdded) {
  setSumCargoValue(sumCargoValue * 1 + item.value * 1);
} else {
  setSumCargoValue(sumCargoValue * 1 - item.value * 1);
}

 onBookmarkClick();
```

}

I want the total weight (sumCargoValue) to be passed to the parent component. There it should be displayed on the scoreboard.

Parent-component:

```
function CheckWeightCargoFrame({ openPopup }) {
...
  const [sumCargoValue, setsumCargoValue] = useState();
  const [BookmarkClick, setBookmarkClick] = useState("");


  function onBookmarkClick() {
    setBookmarkClick(!setBookmarkClick);
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("selectCargo"));
    setsumCargoValue(localStorage.getItem("selectCargo"));
  }

...

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("selectCargo"));
    setsumCargoValue(localStorage.getItem("selectCargo"));
  } );

 return (
...
        <ListArray
          array={cargo}
          filter={"cargo"}
          onBookmarkClick={onBookmarkClick}
... 
        />
      )}

      <div className="check-weight__info"> {sumCargoValue}
      </div>
...
```

Now the total weight with the parent component is the same after every second click on the weight button in the child component. Although the local storage is recorded in a timely and correct manner.

How to make the correct rendering after a long press?

Answer (score 0):

Child-component

```
function Child({ array, filter, cargoButtonClick }) {
     ...
     const  cargoButtonHandler = (event) => {
        const item = event;
        setLotsSplice(
          lotsSplice.map((elem) =>
            elem.id === item.id ? { ...elem, isAdded: !elem.isAdded } : elem
          )
        );
        cargoButtonClick(event);
      };

     ...
      
     return (
    ... 
    {filter == "cargo" &&
                lotsSplice.map((item) => (
                  <CargoButton
                    key={item.id}
                    id={item.id}
                    weight_value={item.value}
                    zn={item.zn}
                    handleClick={cargoButtonHandler}
                    array={lotsSplice}
                    card={item}
                  />
                ))}
    ...
}
```

Parent-component

```
    ...
      const cargoButtonClick = (item) => {
        if (!item.isAdded) {
          setSumCargoValue(sumCargoValue + item.value * 1);
        } else {
          setSumCargoValue(sumCargoValue - item.value * 1);
        }
      };

  ...

  return (
        <Child
          array={cargo}
          filter={"cargo"}
          cargoButtonClick={cargoButtonClick}
        />
      )}

      <div className="check-weight__info">{sumCargoValue}</div>
    ...
```